# How to redirect to the previous page in asp.net after session expires

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm working on a project in which a login session is created when the user enters his email and password
 but after some time when the session expires then login page appears and when I enter the details then  I'm redirected to the home page
Is there any way to get back to the previous page before the session expired?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to break it to ya, but there is no way to redirect at Session_End as there is no client there! You will just be redirected to the destinationurl when the session ends!

You can redirect to a login though! Open your Web.config file, and set your session timeout to 1 minute like this:

```
<system.web>   
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1"/>   
</system.web>
```

Now open the Global.asax file and write the following code for the Session_Start Event:

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)    
 {   
   // Code that runs when a new session is started   
   if (Session["LoginUserName"] != null)   
   {   
   //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null   
      Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");   

   }   
 else   
  {   
   //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires    
      Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");   

  }
```

In the code above of the Global.asax file if the session is null then the page is redirected to Login.aspx. If not then it redirects to Welcome.aspx. I did this logic in the Global.asax file because the Global.asax file events are fired globally.

Now the entire Global.asax file will be as follows:

```
  <%@ Application Language="C#" %>   
  <script RunAt="server">   

  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)   
  {   
    // Code that runs on application startup   

 }   

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown   

}   

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs   

}   

   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){

    // Code that runs when a new session is started   
   if (Session["LoginUserName"] != null)   
   {   
        //Redirect to Welcome Page if Session is not null   
        Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");   

    }   
    else   
  {   
        //Redirect to Login Page if Session is null & Expires    
     Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");   

    }   


}   

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
  // Code that runs when a session ends.    
 // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode   
   // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer    
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.   

    }   

    </script>
```

Now open the Login.aspx.cs page and write the following code in the Login Button click:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
 {   

     Session["LoginUserName"] = Convert.ToString(TextBox1.Text);   
     Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");   
  }
```

In the code above, first we are storing Login User Name in the Session so we can get Login User Name at the Next Page and then we redirect the page to the Welcome.aspx Page.

Now write the following code in the Welcome.aspx.cs page as:

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;   
using System.Web;   
using System.Web.UI;   
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;   

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page   
{   
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
 Label1.Text="WelCome    " +Convert.ToString(Session["LoginUserName"]);   

}   
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{   
    Response.Redirect("AddUserDetails.aspx");   
}   
}
```

In the code above, after the user logs into the application it is redirected to the Welcome.aspx page so we are taking the current user login name on page load from Session and assigned to the label.

I have added another page that is AddUserDetails.aspx and called it from the code above that determines if the session has expired. If it is expired then it will redirect to the AddUserDetails.aspx page otherwise it goes to the Login.aspx page.

Now our application is ready for testing, so let us run the application. The following Login Page will be shown.